# How to set logo on navigation bar in bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add logo on navigation bar but it's not showing logo, i searched lot but never get any relevant answer for that.

error :- you can see on top of left side on navigation

[image]

code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../../../public/logo/logo.png" >
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

File stucture :-

[image]

Note :I put `logo.png` on same directory and logo size is: `225x225 px`

Thank You!

Comment: It's not finding the image. Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: Means its not finding the image, try changing src value to src="/logo.png" or src="~/logo.png"

Comment: @ZimSystem , Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @RyanWilson tried not working

Comment: Does `logo.png` exist? If so, where is it located? Double-check your directory structure and confirm the relationship between your html file and the image.

Comment: @JPLew see the screenshot of file structure , i think it's not having any issue !

Comment: A good strategy is to perform some sanity checks. First, swap the relative path with the absolute url to your image: `D:\website\kdblue...`. Next, try to duplicate your image and move it right next to your handlebars file, then link it like this: `src="download.png"`. Once you can confirm that, then try to figure out the correct relative path.

Comment: @JPLew tried both method not working !

Comment: ok, then try to get any image to load, like the google logo: `https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`

Comment: @JPLew Thank You! It's working but how can i place my logo?

Comment: you just have to figure out the correct relative path. your `../`s aren't going where you think they're going, so keep experimenting